# MS Access VBA to set current selection/record to null on a continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form with a subform that is a continuous form.  I have a tab control that displays information related to the record selected in the continuous form; the tab control displays as soon as a record is selected/clicked.  That all is grand.

However, after the user updates information in the tab control and clicks a button, I want to hide the tab control until a record is actually clicked on the continuous form.

What is currently happening is that the first record in the continuous subform is selected and I'd like for no record to be selected.

Is there a way to set the current record/selection of a continuous form to nothing or null?  I've tried setting the bookmark on the continuous form to null in the button click event using `Parent.SubApptList.Form.Bookmark = Null` and that does not work for me.

Seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

After the button click event could you set focus to the parent form? Doing this would force the user to click on a record. Maybe I'm not fully understanding exactly what you're trying to do but if all you want is for nothing to have focus after a button event then that's the route I would take. That's assuming you don't having any on focus events for thr main form.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Harvey. Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem either because once the button in the tab control is clicked and the continuous form is updated, the first record is selected even when the parent form is given the focus. I ended up solving this by just forcing the subform in the click event to update the tab control even if the currently selected item is clicked; before that was not occurring and could prevent the user from getting the updated info for the 1st record, but forcing the subform to update even when the current record is selected worked for what I need.